# How to disable /enable or change the default warning Sound for Pyqt5 QMessageBox?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How to disable/enable the warning sounds in PyQt5?. Is it possible to enable/disable or change the default warning sounds programmatically?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QApplication

class MsgBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(). __init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Msgbox")

        msgbox = QMessageBox()
        msgbox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msgbox.setText(" Item Not Found. Want to create one...")
        msgbox.setWindowTitle("Assist - Warning Information")
        msgbox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        returnvalue = msgbox.exec_()
        if msgbox.clickedButton() is msgbox.button(QMessageBox.Yes):
            print("yes button pressed")

        if msgbox.clickedButton() is msgbox.button(QMessageBox.No):
            print("No button pressed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MsgBox()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It seems you're talking about *system sounds*. And I suppose you're on Windows, right?

Comment: yes sir. I am using windows  @musicamante

Comment: @tckraoumuqnt unfortunately I can't help you with that since I don't use that OS, but consider that: 1. Qt tries, whenever possible, to use *system* implementations (including system sounds), so you should look for python implementations that allow disabling such features; 2. Consider using a basic QDialog with a QDialogButtonBox instead.

Comment: Thankyou @musicamante